# How to convert depth to disparity

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, neural-network, deep-learning

if $k = \text{baseline}\cdot\text{focal length}$ is known, then the disparity is the ratio of $k$ to depth $d_\text{image}$:

$$D_\text{image} = \frac{k}{d_\text{image}}$$

I have a `uint16` depth image in the range $0,\ldots,65535$ and would like to get the disparity image.

Taking $D_\text{image} = \frac{k}{d_\text{image}}$ wil yield a result in the range $1/65535,\ldots,\infty$.

How do I deal with the infinite value of the disparity image if I were to use to train a Neural Net as a target?

If it was the depth image, I could divide it by 65535 to get it in the range [0-1] for training but I am not sure how to go about it with the obtained disparity images.

Answer (score 1):

physically, you can't have an object at 0 depth; that would place it *inside* the focal point. So, the observation you've got is erroneous.

The intuitive thing to do is to clip: either your minimum distance to 1, or your maximum disparity to some fixed value.

Dividing by a constant is just scaling, and should have no influence on your deep learning anyway. It also doesn't solve the division-by-zero problem at all!

Comment: Yes, Marcus, thank you for your answer. So since the depth image is in range [0 - 65535], should the disparity image be in the range [1 - 65535] then? That way I could scale the obtained down to [0-1] to use to train. I am learning this and don't know how people typical handle this issue for deep learning.

Comment: If I clip the disparity image to [1, 65535] and they normalize by dividing by 35535 to get it to [0-1] the obtained image is just all black and it does not seen like a model will learn from it.

Comment: Even displaying the [1-65535] version of the disparity image appear as a binary black/white image.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing exactly, but this is just basic math, and might be integer rounding biting you! So, do this on paper and check your math is right.

Comment: Yes, I should have explained better. So, I have a set of depth images which have locations where depth is undefined is set of 0 pixel value. I am trying to train a model to predict disparity. If I chose to clip the the depth image to [1-65535], then the disparity image will be in [1/65535 -1] which is no longer taking the consideration the lacations where depth was undefined.